# Creating a join on multiple foreign keys using Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query my database using Sqlalchemy ORM methods. I have created the tables and the engine as well as testing raw sql against it. I want to be able to use a Location code as a parameter from the locations table and pull the origin / destination from the trip table. Here is the code below:

```
Base = declarative_base () # generated base class orm

class Trip(Base):
    __tablename__="trips"
    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    route =Column("Route", String(25))
    origin_id = Column("origin_id", String(10), ForeignKey("locations.locationCode"))
    destination_id = Column("destination_id", String(10), ForeignKey("locations.locationCode"))

    origin = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[origin_id])
    destination = relationship("Location", foreign_keys=[destination_id])

   
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = "locations"
    locationCode = Column("locationCode",String(10), primary_key = True)
    latitude = Column("latitude", String(25))
    longitude = Column("longitude", String(25))
    facilityOwnedByCarvana = Column("facilityOwnedByCarvana",Integer)


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///carvana.db")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
locationsDF = pd.read_csv("data/locations.csv")
tripsDf = pd.read_csv("data/trips.csv")
locationsDF.to_sql(con=engine, name=Location.__tablename__, if_exists="replace", index=False)
tripsDf.to_sql(con=engine, name=Trip.__tablename__,if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Here is my attempt at the query

```
q = (
    session.query(Location)
    .outerjoin(Trip, Location.locationCode == Trip.destination_id)
    .filter(Location.locationCode == "BALT")
    .order_by(Location.locationCode)
    .limit(10)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

General:

```
        db_session.query(class_table1)
                  .join(class_table2, 
                  class_table2.key_table2 == class_table1.key_table1, 
                  isouter=True)
```

Specific:

```
        db_session.query(Location)
                  .join(Trip, 
                  Trip.destination_id== Location.locationCode , 
                  isouter=True)
```